# Click outside component to unfocus

Tags: wpf, xaml

By default, I need to focus on another component (a button or a textBox) to unfocus from the current one.
I want to just click outside.
So for example if I click on a textBox and write something, than click outside the TextBox, I shouldn't be able to type because the component is unfocused.

(I hope my explanation is clear, if not, please say so in the comments)

Comment: so, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by attaching to `PreviewMouseDown` event of a `Window`. Also in order to **Lose Focus** you need another focusable control (e.g. a text box named `_dummyControl`) to move focus to.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.PreviewMouseDown += PreviewMouseDownEventHandler;
}
private void PreviewMouseDownEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //check conditions here...
    _dummyControl.Focus();
}
```

---

more info:

`PreviewMouseDown` event occurs just before a `MouseDown` or click event occurs. By attaching to this event your code can tell when user clicks on the window and at that time you should move focus to a hidden control to simulate unfocus functionality.

Comment: Can you explain this solution more indepth? I don't know a lot about event handlers and so... I was actually hoping for a built in solution.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I gave you the actual code for that. anyway, I added more info